# How to open a zip file which contains my dataset in multiple txt format files, which I have to convert in data frame in python

Tags: pandas, zip

I have a zip file, which has many .txt format files, which I need to put into a single data frame.

The examples of my files are like in the below screenshot.[the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0sK6.jpg)

All have to be in a data frame to do machine learning practice, can anyone help me out.

Comment: Are all files in the same format? Check out: `os.listdir()` to get the list of .txt files. Then use `pandas.read_csv()` and `pandas.append()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ZipFile`:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

zip = ZipFile('data.zip')
dfs = [pd.read_csv(zip.open(text_file.filename))
           for text_file in zip.infolist()]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe playing with this and going further as required helps...

Give files in a zip like...

[image]

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd
from zipfile import ZipFile

df = pd.concat(
    [pd.read_csv(ZipFile('names.zip').open(i), header=None, encoding='ISO-8859-1') for i in ZipFile('names.zip').namelist()],
    ignore_index=True
)
df = df.dropna(thresh=2)
df.rename(columns={0:'Name', 1:'Gender?', 2:'Number'}, inplace=True)
df['Number'] = df.Number.astype(int)
print(df)
```

**Outputs:**

```
     Name       Gender?     Number
0    Mary       F           7065
1    Anna       F           2604
2    Emma       F           2003
3  Minnie       F           1746
6    John       M           8135
7    Fred       M           4576
8  George       M           3022
9   Roger       M           4617
```